# How to get current canvas?

Tags: android, view, android-canvas

I have DrawView. If I touch this view it draws small circles. I wont to draw circles but not to touch view - with help function "setPoints". What I do:

```
package com.samples;
import ...

public class DrawView extends View {
    ArrayList<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    private int pSize = 5;
    private int pColor = Color.BLACK;

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.setOnTouchListener(this);
                    Point point = new Point();
                    point.x = event.getX();
                    point.y = event.getY();
                    points.add(point); 
                    invalidate();
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        requestFocus();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
        for (Point point : points) {
            canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, pSize, paint);
        }
    }

    public void setPoints(Float xP, Float yP)
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.x = xP;
        point.y = yP;
        points.add(point);
        postInvalidate();
    }
}

class Point {
    float x, y;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x + ", " + y;
    }
}
```

Please tell me, how get canvas out setPoints function?

**Update:**
Wow, it's really interesting problem. My DrawView contains in HorizontalScrollView. Because if I set in this DrawView right coordinates, no one knows where are drawable circles.

Comment: This question is hard to understand. Please review it

Comment: It's not easy do decipher what you want to accomplish :) First thing, remove that `canvas2`: it doesn't work as you think. I suspect you want to retain previously drawn circle, don't you? If this is your goal, you have to maintain a history of draw calls, and can do it in two ways: 1) you store an array `Point[]` and draw each circle in `onDraw`; or 2) each time a circle is added you update a cache the `Bitmap`

Comment: I wont to draw this circle but do not touch the screen!

Comment: I realize it. I write socket-drawer. Player_1 have DrawView and can touch it. Player_2 have DrawView but can't touch it. Player_1 set touch-coordinates per Server and Player_2 get it. It's work. Player_1 can draw circles and I see it. Player_2 get it correctly (Socket connection class send coordinates out server to DrawView class, I see it in Log (Log.v("pnts.substring", pnts2);)) But I can't call onDraw in setPoints function because I never call/create/get it and it's my problem - Player_2 don't see Player_1 's circles.

Comment: When you receive a new Point, add it to a List<Point> and call View.postInvalidate(). This will call your onDraw(), which you'll modify to loop through List<Point> and draw a circle for each Point on the Canvas passed to onDraw (which is canvas, not canvas2!)

Comment: I updated the code. See it please

Comment: You don't have to prefix postInvalidate() with anything. It's an object method. Just call postInvalidate()

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7557/discussion-between-user1136218-and-raffaele)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. The canvas is managed by the system and is passed to your `onDraw()`. I don't understand why you'd need it outside of there. Just redeclare `setPoints` like this

```
public void setPoints(Canvas canvas, Float xP, Float Yp)
```

You can keep a cache of the previous drawings (or store the previous points)

Comment: Points are not pproblem, I keep it. About "Canvas canvas": What can i doing if never call onDraw?

Comment: You seem not to know how Android draw Views. When the system detects that a widget needs to (re)paint, it knocks on your widget's door and it responds by `onDraw(Canvas)`. So you are guaranteed that this method will be called each and every time is needed. One way to _trigger_ _the_ _repaint_ is by calling `invalidate()` (or `postInvalidate`). So you never have to call onDraw yourself, but be sure that Android will call it when needed. You need to supply the callback. Also, please specify what you mean with "I want to draw circles but not to touch view"

Comment: Can you give me link or keyword?

Comment: The documentation is sparse. [2D drawing guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#on-view), [View API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas))

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring canvas2 as a public variable in the DrawView class.

Comment: Problem is only in Canvas call.

Answer (score 1):

You draw your circles in `onDraw()`.  That's the way `View` is supposed to work (technically it's actually in the `draw()` method but we'll overlook that).  In `setPoints()`, set the points of the circle in variables within the class scope, call `invalidate()`, then draw the circle like that in `onDraw()`.  If you follow this method, you're following the class flow that the view was designed for.

Comment: hmm.. public void setPoints(Float xP, Float Yp)
    {
        canvas2.drawCircle(xP, yP, 5, paint); invalidate();
    } so?

Comment: No. `canvas2.drawCircle(xP, yP, 5, paint);` goes in `onDraw()`.  You save the values for `xP`, `yP` then call `invalidate()` in `setPoints()`